# When I perform placement new on trivial object, Is it guaranteed to preserve the object/value representation?

Tags: c++, placement-new

```
struct A
{
    int x;
}

A t{};
t.x = 5;

new (&t) A;

// is it always safe to assume that t.x is 5?
assert(t.x == 5);
```

As far as I know, when a trivial object of class type is created, the compiler can omit the call of explicit or implicit default constructor because no initialization is required.
(is that right?)

Then, If placement new is performed on a trivial object whose lifetime has already begun, is it guaranteed to preserve its object/value representation?
(If so, I want to know where I can find the specification..)

Comment: No, this is not safe.  You never initialized the member when constructing, so you are reading an indeterminate value.

Comment: In this pseudo-code, where the comment & assert are located, it is always safe to assume that t.x is uninitialized (*because it is uninitialized*) and accessing it before it has been initialized is **undefined behavior**.

Comment: @Eljay is placement new regarded as default-initialization in the above code? that's why t.x after placement new is uninitialized while `A t{}` initializes t.x by performing zero-initializaiton?

Comment: Placement `new` ends the lifetime of the object that previously occupied the storage (if you didn't previously end it with a call to the destructor). It is a good habit to use the return value of the `new` expression instead of using reusing `t`.

Comment: Imagine you have a DS9K computer.  For that computer, every byte of memory has status bits:  r, w, x, and e.  For an uninitialized byte of memory, e-bit is set, r-bit is clear, w-bit is set.  If read with the e-bit set, the read faults and the program abends.  If written to, the e-bit is cleared, the r-bit is set, and then future reads succeed.  Your C++ compiler's optimizer knows these things.  Trying to dance around the compiler's understanding of the C++ abstract machine will only end in tears.

Comment: [What Every C Programmer Should Know About Undefined Behavior](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html), also applies to C++.  The answer from aschepler makes a good case that the code is actually safe.  I would not rely on this in production code.

Comment: [clang says it's uninitialized](https://godbolt.org/z/nb9xqs59r) (though this example might not be equivalent)

Comment: Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/14659752

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, let's ask some compilers for their opinion. Reading an indeterminate value is UB, which means that if it occurs inside a constant expression, it must be diagnosed. We can't directly use placement `new` in a constant expression, but we *can* use `std::construct_at` (which has a typed interface). I also modified the class `A` slightly so that value-initialization does the same thing as default-initialization:

```
#include <memory>

struct A
{
    int x;
    constexpr A() {}
};

constexpr int foo() {
    A t;
    t.x = 5;
    std::construct_at(&t);
    return t.x;
}

static_assert(foo() == 5);
```

As you can see [on Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/1zoYdGWrz), Clang, ICC, and MSVC all reject the code, saying that `foo()` is not a constant expression. Clang and MSVC additionally indicate that they have a problem with the read of `t.x`, which they consider to be a read of an uninitialized value.

[P0593](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/p0593r6.html#type-punning), while not directly related to this issue, contains an explanation that seems relevant:

> The properties ascribed to objects and references throughout this document apply for a given object or reference only during its lifetime.

That is, reusing the storage occupied by an object in order to create a new object always destroys whatever *value* was held by the old object, because an object's value dies with its lifetime. Now, objects of type `A` are [transparently replaceable](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.life#8) by other objects of type `A`, so it is permitted to continue to use the name `t` even after its storage has been reused. That does not imply that the new `t` holds the value that the old `t` does. It only means that `t` is not a dangling reference to the old object.

Going off what is said in P0593, GCC is wrong and the other compilers are right. In constant expression evaluation, this kind of code is required to be diagnosed. Otherwise, it's just UB.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but isn't `constexpr A() {}` ill-formed, NDR? I was under the impression that a constructor cannot be a constant expression unless it initializes all data members -- which would make the `std::construct_at(...)` test inconclusive. I don't disagree with the conclusion at all; but I think using a potentially bad constant expression doesn't prove it. Not sure if C++20 changed this rule to be valid for some reason

Comment: @Human-Compiler The restriction you are talking about was lifted in C++20. Prior to C++20, it was IF (not IFNDR).

Comment: Can you provide a reference to the relevant passage from the C++20 standard that lifts said restriction? The [value-initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization) page on cppreference mentions that all known compilers perform additional zero-initialization when an object is default-initialized to an indeterminate value in contexts where constant evaluation is required, which actually is non-compliant behavior.

Comment: @303 https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1331r2.pdf is the paper that removed the restriction for C++20. The cppreference page is talking about a more subtle situation that I don't have space to explain in the comment section.

Answer (score 2):

From looking at the Standard, the program has undefined behavior because of an invalid use of an object with indeterminate value.

Per [[basic.life]/8](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/basic.life#8), since the object of type `A` created by the placement *new-expression* exactly overlays the original object `t`, using the name `t` after that point refers to the `A` object created by the *new-expression*.

In [[basic.indet]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/basic.indet#1), we have:

> When storage for an object with automatic or dynamic storage duration is obtained, the object has an indeterminate value, and if no initialization is performed for the object, that object retains an indeterminate value until that value is replaced ([expr.ass]).

One important detail here (which I missed at first) is that "obtaining storage" is different from "allocating storage" or the storage duration of a storage region. The "obtain storage" words are also used to define the beginning of an object's lifetime in [[basic.life]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/basic.life#1) and in the context of a *new-expression* in [[expr.new]/10](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/expr.new#10):

> A new-expression may obtain storage for the object by calling an allocation function ([basic.stc.dynamic.allocation]). ... [ *Note:* ... The set of allocation and deallocation functions that may be called by a *new-expression* may include functions that do not perform allocation or deallocation; for example, see [new.delete.placement]. — *end note* ]

So the placement *new-expression* "obtains storage" for the object of type `A` and its subobject of type `int` when it calls `operator new(void*)`. For this purpose, it doesn't make a difference that the memory locations in the storage region actually have static storage duration. Since "no initialization is performed" for the created subobject of type `int` with dynamic storage duration, it has an indeterminate value.

See also [this Q&A: What does it mean to obtain storage?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58356588/459640)